# "come to look for" VS "come looking for"

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference in between those below?

> He's waiting for us to come to look for him.
>
> He's waiting for us to come looking for him.

If not, is there any in another contexts other than "He's waiting..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way is fine, although it's important to note that I would say *come look for* rather than *come to look for*. *Come to look for* just sounds unnatural.

> He's waiting for us to come look for him.
>
> He's waiting for us to come looking for him.

I don't have any grammar rule or research to back that up, though, I'm too tired at the moment.

I also can't think of any specific circumstance where one would be grammatically correct and the other not, although you shouldn't quote me on that.